# XML DTD - Defining attributes as numbers and requiring #PCDATA

Tags: xml, dtd

I realize Schema is the way to go, but this is an assignment. If I wanted to require an attribute on some element to be a float/number, is that possible?  The only thing I know to do is to define it as CDATA - is there some predefined ENTITY ?  I don't think I should pull in any other DTD, so if it's that complex, it's incorrect for the purposes of this assignment.  Right now I do it like so:

`<!ATTLIST elemName attrName CDATA>`

Is this just a limitation of DTD?

Additionally, is there a way to require #PCDATA on an element?  I'm using Altova XML Spy and it is allowing elements with:

`<elem foo="bar"/>`

for something defined like:

`<!ELEMENT elem (#PCDATA)>`
    `<!ATTLIST elem foo CDATA #REQUIRED>`

past the validation.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there doesn't appear to be a way to specify only numbers and the empty string is valid for `#PCDATA`.